# entry_fn(i, j) to make a matrix

Tags: python

Upon reading such an example from book "data science from scratch"

> We’ll also want to be able to create a matrix given its shape and a function for generating its elements. We can do this using a nested list comprehension:

```
from typing import Callable

def make_matrix(num_rows: int,
                num_cols: int,
                entry_fn: Callable[[int, int], float]) -> Matrix:
    """
    Returns a num_rows x num_cols matrix
    whose (i,j)-th entry is entry_fn(i, j)
    """
    return [[entry_fn(i, j)             # given i, create a list
            for j in range(num_cols)]  #   [entry_fn(i, 0), ... ]
            for i in range(num_rows)]   # create one list for each i
```

What does `entry_fn` do here?

I assume it should be a matrix, so you can make s sub-matrix from a given matrix.

Answer (score 2):

`entry_fn` is not a matrix, it is a function. That is the reason for the `_fn` suffix on the name.

You as the programmer are to define a regular function that takes two `int` parameters and returns a `float` value. The parameters are the row number and the column number of a location in your desired matrix, and the return value is the desired value of the matrix at that row and column.

To build a matrix, the routine `make_matrix` needs to know what values are to go in to the matrix. You define a function that provides those values. In Python, functions are first-class objects, which means you can do things with functions. In particular, you can pass the name of the function to another function.

Here is an example that creates and prints an identity matrix (of float values) of size 4 x 4. The name `Matrix` must already be defined before this code.

```
from typing import Callable

def make_matrix(num_rows: int,
                num_cols: int,
                entry_fn: Callable[[int, int], float]) -> Matrix:
    """
    Returns a num_rows x num_cols matrix
    whose (i,j)-th entry is entry_fn(i, j)
    """
    return [[entry_fn(i, j)             # given i, create a list
             for j in range(num_cols)]  #   [entry_fn(i, 0), ... ]
            for i in range(num_rows)]   # create one list for each i

def kronecker_delta(i: int, j:int) -> float:
    return 1.0 if (i == j) else 0.0

print(make_matrix(4, 4, kronecker_delta))
```

Comment: Nice example with Kronecker's delta. An another example would be `lambda i,j: random.random()` for `entry_fun` to generate a matrix with random values from range [0.0, 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

`entry_fn` is a [2-variable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_real_variables) which takes `i` and `j` as its parameters.